# New pypi org proxy not working with sonatype nexus

Tags: python, nexus, pypi, sonatype

Ever since https://pypi.python.org moved https://pypi.org. Our nexus repository is unable to pull the packages from this.
Has anyone came across this issue and what is the solution for it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?

Comment: can you show your configuration for pypi?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be the case of an outbound firewall rules blocking access to either `pypi.org` or `files.pythonhosted.org`. Make sure those are not blocked for your Nexus instance. Additionally, if you are using SSL in your Nexus configuration, you need to trust the new domains (notice that they use different certificate each).

Comment: Yep.. got it solved by whitelisting few mirror URL in firewall :)